# How to install catkin on a virtual machine Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04, ros, catkin

I think I have indigo...
I followed the instructions: https://wiki.ros.org/catkin#Installing_catkin

Can someone please help me with this?  I used a virtualbox to run Ubuntu 18.04.  Can catkin work with indigo?  I'm lost...

```
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/build/build$ **sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-catkin**
[sudo] password for notsotechnical: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
**E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-catkin**
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/build/build$ sudo apt-get install cmake python-catkin-pkg python-empy python-nose python-setuptools libgtest-dev build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
python-setuptools is already the newest version (39.0.1-2).
libgtest-dev is already the newest version (1.8.0-6).
python-empy is already the newest version (3.3.2-1build1).
python-nose is already the newest version (1.3.7-3).
cmake is already the newest version (3.10.2-1ubuntu2.18.04.1).
python-catkin-pkg is already the newest version (0.4.13-100).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-catkin-pkg : Depends: python-catkin-pkg-modules (>= 0.4.13) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/build/build$ **apt --fix-broken install**
**E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?**
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/build/build$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the problem:
Ubuntu 18.04 runs with ros melodic, not indigo. SO follow your link, but on the very top you need to switch to melodic instead of indigo.

Comment: did you fix it, if so how?

Comment: The edit is from the author of the question who apparently changed my answer to something completely different and kind of made a follow up question out of my answer...